# Identify which scrollbar is active

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, scrollbar

I have multiple scrollbars to my page, but can't make them working properly :

```
 <div class="dates-container" v-for="id in ids">
    <overlay-scrollbars
      :ref="`datesHeader`+id"
      :options="datesScrollOptions"
      :key="id"
    >
 </div>
  ......
  resetScroller() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (this.$refs[`datesHeader${this.currentRoom}`][0]) {
        const inst = this.$refs[`datesHeader${this.currentRoom}`][0].osInstance();
        if (inst == null) return;
        const state = inst.getState();
        if (state.hasOverflow.x) {
          inst.scroll({ x: 0 });
        }
        this.updateScrollButtons();
      }
    });
  },
```

Like that is working fine; The problem is when I tried to identify which scrollbar was moved and how I can update `this.currentRoom` when scrollbar is moved;

Answer (score -1):

Firsty u have wrong :ref value - should be `` :ref="`datesHeader-${id}`" ``

then on onMounted you can add event listners to $refs

```
onMounted() {
 this.$refs['datesHeader-0'].addEventLister('scroll', watchFunc)
}
```

DOCS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

remember to remove event listeners in onBeforeUnmount

also, IntersectionObserver could be good for tracking scroll

DOCS: https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API